# How to show custom intervals on xticks for time series plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, xticks

I'd like to change the `xticks` on my plot. Shown here is a time series for my parameter of interest, with

- y14 = years 1930-1959
- y24 = years 1960-1989
- y34 = years 1990-2020.

Whereas B14, B24, and B34 are numbers ranging from 0-200. I want to change the `xticks` to only show the beginning and end of each time period. i.e 1930, 1960, 1990, & 2020.

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(y14,B14, 'o')
plt.plot(y24,B24, 'o')
plt.plot(y34,B34, 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

I've tried to change the number of bins by using

```
plt.locator_params(axis= 'x', tight=True, nbins=4)
```

However this did not get me where I want. I'm wondering if changing the spacing between bins to 30 years at the same time would do the trick? Or if anybody has any suggestions. Even showing the first `xtick` value (1930) has proven difficult for a beginner.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) you can achieve your goal?

```
plt.xticks([1930, 1960, 1990, 2020])
```

[image]